# "which" equivalent for shared libraries

Tags: c, dynamic-linking

I am looking for a utility that would behave in the same way as `which`, but to look up shared libraries (*.so) in the directories defined in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an executable and you want to see where it's picking up libraries, run

```
ldd /path/to/executable
```

This will account for libraries on the default search path as well as libraries in this executable's [rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) if any.

On Linux, paths to system libraries are cached for efficiency. `/sbin/ldconfig -p` displays the contents of the cache (it's stored in `/etc/ld.so.cache`). Here's a script that shows the location(s) of a library:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ]; then
  set -f
  IFS=:
  for d in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH; do
    if [ -e "$d/$1" ]; then echo "$1"; fi
  done
fi
/sbin/ldconfig -p |
awk -v needle="$1" '$1 == needle {sub(/.* => /, ""); print}'
```

Answer (score 7):

If your libraries are properly cached you should be abled to find it via:

```
ldconfig -p|grep "yourlibrary"
```

If you search for a library that came with your distribution you could use the distribution means of searching for files within packages.

- zypper wp "*/library.so"     (SLES and OpenSuSE)
- yum provides "*/library.so"  (RedHat and its clones)

This will also output rpms that are not installed, but are part of your active installation sources.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a utility that will work like `gcc`'s `-lLIBNAME` flag, which looks for a file called `libLIBNAME.so` then you could probably use a little script that does something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ldpath="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-$(</etc/ld.so.conf)}"
notfound=1
for libdir in ${ldpath//:/ }; do
        (test -f "$libdir/lib${1}.so" && echo "$_") && notfound=0
done
[ "$notfound" -eq 0 ]
```