# Command to list the directories in which to look for shared libraries?

Tags: dynamic-linking

I've read [`which` equivalent for shared libraries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22178/49371) and [Where do executables look for shared objects at runtime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22926/49371), but **is there a command to list all the directories** in which the shared libraries will be searched?

Something like a command that auto-computes all the list explained in the second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short: no

long: The related environment variables are system- and configuration-dependent.  For a given system/configuration, you could write a script which does this.

*[Where do executables look for shared objects at runtime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime)* gives some insight, but is incomplete.  It mentions OSX and Solaris, but focuses on Linux, pointing to two resources:

- [Program Library HOWTO: 3. Shared Libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) (which mentions `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` without mentioning the less-often `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64`, and also gives a one-line mention of **rpath**).
- [ld.so, ld-linux.so* - dynamic linker/loader](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), which again mentions some of the environment variables and *rpath*.

You would also find these useful:

- [ldconfig - configure dynamic linker run-time bindings](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html), Linux-specific (neither OSX or Solaris):

  > **`ldconfig`** creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent
  >   shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command
  >   line, in the file **`/etc/ld.so.conf`**, and in the trusted directories,
  >   **`/lib`** and **`/usr/lib`** (on some 64-bit architectures such as x86-64, lib
  >   and **`/usr/lib`** are the trusted directories for 32-bit libraries, while
  >   **`/lib64`** and **`/usr/lib64`** are used for 64-bit libraries).
- [How do shared libraries work in a mixed 64bit/32bit system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706328/how-do-shared-libraries-work-in-a-mixed-64bit-32bit-system)
- [shlib script](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/misc/shlib), a utility script in ncurses listing a variety of environment variables used for specifying where shared libraries are.

In particular, "**`sudo ldconfig -v`**"

> **`-v`**, **`--verbose`**
>   Verbose mode.  Print current version number, the name of each
>   directory as it is scanned, and any links that are created.
>   Overrides quiet mode.

which is *close* to what was asked, but gives lots of extraneous information.  (And it is largely Linux-specific, though BSDs use it — but different, [see manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ldconfig)).  If you make some assumptions about its output format, you could get directories from this using

```
sudo ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep ':$' |sed -e 's/://'
```

which gives (on one system)

```
/usr/local/lib
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib
/usr/lib
```

To recap: there is no *command*, but you can make a script, which is system-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

On a GNU system

```
ldconfig -p | tail -n +2 | grep -o '/.*/' | sort -u
```

Would give you the directories where dynamic libraries are found in the cache. You can add the ones in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Here with `zsh` syntax:

```
(
  ldconfig -p | tail -n +2 | grep -o '/.*/'
  [ -n "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ] && printf '%s/\n' ${${(s/:/)LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:A}
) | sort -u
```

Also note that at least on my x86_64 GNU system, and for 64 bit executables, for each of those directories, it also searches in `$dir/x86_64`, `$dir/tls` and `$dir/tls/x86_64`.

Also note that executables can hard code paths to libraries in them. Still with the  GNU dynamic linker, you could use `LD_DEBUG=libs` to get the search paths, for instance with something like (here for 64bit ELF executables on my GNU/Linux system):

```
$ LD_DEBUG=libs /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --inhibit-cache /bin/true 2>&1 |
   sed '/.*search path=/!d;s///;s/[[:blank:]]*([^)]*)$//' |
   tr : '\n' |
   sort -u
/home/stephane/lib
/home/stephane/lib/tls
/home/stephane/lib/tls/x86_64
/home/stephane/lib/x86_64
/lib
/lib/tls
/lib/tls/x86_64
/lib/x86_64
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/tls
/usr/lib/tls/x86_64
/usr/lib/x86_64
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64
```

Comment: *it also searches in `$dir/x86_64`, `$dir/tls` and `$dir/tls/x86_64`* – do you know how is this behavior configured?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a command. However, `/etc/ld.so.conf` and possibly all files under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` plus whatever you find in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` yields the answer to the question *where are shared libraries searched for?*.

Caution: executables may define additional or alternative search paths.

You could also use `ldd` on all files in the search path in order to see where the dynamic linker actually searches. The following approach takes a while and is certainly not award winning:

```
ldd /bin/* /usr/bin/* /sbin/* /usr/sbin/* 2>/dev/null | grep '=>' | awk '{print $3;}' | xargs dirname | sort -u
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of a specific command that will list all shared libraries, but you could use a bit of a "fudge" workaround by just running

```
which <non-existent command/alias>
```

and look at the output such as:

```
[$]› which fake-command
/usr/bin/which: no fake-command in (/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

or find any directory ending in *bin

```
find / -name *bin -type d
```

but that will more than likely pull too many results that won't be in a shared library

Comment: Doesn't `which` just search in the `$PATH`? That's true for executables - but not libraries.